# How to cast an agtype (vertex or edge) to a regular map

Tags: apache-age

A list of edges needs to be summed by the val property of each edge. `UNWIND` and `sum()` functions were attempted, but `UNWIND` doesn't support agtypes. Is it possible to cast edges to maps to solve this problem, or do you have any **alternative solutions** to suggest?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecasting an edge or vertex to map is not supported and hence any attempt to sum the properties of variable length edges will not succeed.
Check this comment [here](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/730#issuecomment-1456758028) on github issue for alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

Casting is not supported from vertex to map, so *alternately* you can write your own function (more reference [here](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/730#issuecomment-1456758028)).

Another alternate solution would be to update your age repo (as a new [PR](https://github.com/apache/age/pull/736) has been merged) and then use the `UNWIND` clause to work with edges.